# Full Hd Tablet and responsiveness

Tags: responsive-design, tablet

I am about to buy a new tablet that has a 1900x1200 resolution screen and 283 ppi (pixel per inch).

When we develop with bootstrap, we can see the that the breakpoint for tablet is about 750px wide.

Having a tablet with this huge resolution, will my website adapt to the wide, or will I see the whole website with no responsive changes on the 8" screen due to its resolution?

Comment: It will be responsive as most of the mobile browser report a virtual resolution

Comment: I see, but with 1200 pixels wide, will i see the whole website on a tiny screen, with super fonts? or will it adapt like as we minimize browser window ?

Comment: It will most likely adapt show the **Portrait tablets** layout, the font will be in the 283ppi resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real resolution (physical) and virtual (viewport) resolution are two different things.

This site should help you with telling how big the viewport is of any device: http://viewportsizes.com/

As for "Bootstrap breakpoint for tablet", it's just a name. What Bootstrap actually is about is `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg` breakpoints. It does not use any device detecting mechanism, all it's basing on is only the `viewport width`.

**EXAMPLE:**
So if you do have `Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9` that has viewport width of `1280 px` in landscape, your website on landscape will look like on my laptop that has `1280px` width screen. But on portrait your Galaxy Tab will use other breakpoints, as it only has `800 px` width.

**#2 EXAMPLE:**
On [their website](https://www.apple.com/ipad-air-2/), Apple says that `iPad Air` has resolution of `2048x1536` pixels. But as we know, iPad is 'Retina' device, so it's real resolution sizes are twice as long, as it's viewport (so physical resolution is 4 times bigger than virtual). And as we see on http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=ipad%20air (anyone with iPad can check with JavaScript), in reality it has a laughable `1024x768` pixels.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Helped clarify my doubt on the resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

One concrete example I got :

The [Nexus 7 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2013_version)) has a resolution of 1920×1200 (323ppi) with a virtual resolution of 960dp × 600dp.

#### In the Chrome browser Javascript report a resolution of :

- 917x513 in portrait
- 449x217 in lanscape

#### Bootstrap 2 breakpoint report :

- Phone viewport in portrait
- Tablet viewport in lanscape

Comment: Thank you for your response. is also enlightening